# Populate textbox with ajax call to server

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have first and last name text boxes, last name on blur triggers an ajax call to get additional data to fill in other textboxes.  The call is made and I can see in the Chrome dev tool (network tab) that a json string is coming back with all the data, but I can't figure out how to populate the text fields.

ajax function:

```
    $(function() {
        $("#LastName").on('blur', function () {
            var first = $("#FirstName").val();
            var last = $("#LastName").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SearchEmployee", "Employee")',
                type: "GET",
                datatype: 'json',
                data: { 'firstName': first, 'lastName': last },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.ManagerFirst);
                    $("#ManagerFirst").val(data.ManagerFirst);
                    $("#ManagerLast").val(data.ManagerLast);
                },
                error: function () { alert("Huh? What? What did you need?.") }
            });
        })
    })
```

returns something like this:

```
{"EmployeeId":0,"FirstName":"Bob","LastName":"Smith","EmailAddress":null,"ManagerEmail":"Boss.Man@work.org","ManagerId":null,"ManagerFirst":"Boss","ManagerLast":"Man"}
```

The 'alert' shows "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `alert` a data member of the response string, which does not exist. Instead, you should try to convert the string to object, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#LastName").on('blur', function () {
        var first = $("#FirstName").val();
        var last = $("#LastName").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SearchEmployee", "Employee")',
            type: "GET",
            datatype: 'json',
            data: { 'firstName': first, 'lastName': last },
            success: function (data) {
                //converting it to object, since further rows expect this
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                alert(data.ManagerFirst);
                $("#ManagerFirst").val(data.ManagerFirst);
                $("#ManagerLast").val(data.ManagerLast);
            },
            error: function () { alert("Huh? What? What did you need?.") }
        });
    })
})
```

EDIT:

As Bryan Lewis pointed out, it was a typo. This has led to the behavior about which I have written my answer.

Comment: I thought that if the datatype was set to "json" then running parseJSON explicitly was not needed/ gets done for you?  Edit:  Actually the "T" in dataType is supposed to be caps.  Perhaps that was the problem all along?

Comment: I fixed the typo and added the parsing, no difference.  Adding the parseJson line gives error: "Unexpected token o".  I shouldn't have to parse it anyway, the response header is already 'Content-Type: application/json'

Answer (score 0):

You may just have a typo.  Try changing "datatype" to "dataType"

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was the server was returning an array of employee objects, so had to access it like:

```
data[0].ManagerFirst  ... etc.
```

There was no way to tell that from the data I posted, so my apologies.

fyi, once I added that fix, I changed the the dataType param back to 'datatype' and it still worked fine.